# What is "el raspado"?

Tags: traducción, comida

I saw this picture online:

[image]

If you can't see it, it says:

> Y ahora, un Minion poema.
>   Me gusta el helado,
>   me gusta el raspado.
>   Pero mas me gusta
>   estar a tu lado.

I understand all of it except *el raspado*. I looked it up and it means "the scraping". Is there another translation?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=raspado&tbm=isch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some American countries, ["raspado" means](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=raspado):

> *Mx, Ho, Ni, Pa, Ec.* Helado hecho de hielo raspado con jarabe de frutas.

So it just means another kind of ice cream, something like this:

[image: raspado]

Sometimes it helps if you just search the term [in Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspado&tbm=isch). :) (Thanks @rsanchez for the link!)

Comment: Dairy-free.  I've heard it called "shaved ice."

Comment: @aparente001  Does it also happen to have a derogatory meaning?  I had never encountered the word until today when I was reading a newspaper article in which the following was written: _¿Acaso la distancia entre estos últimos y los que superan los 160 puntos no es mayor que la que existe entre los “raspados” y el resto que, en el 70% de los casos, se sitúa en la banda entre 87 y 114 puntos?_  (The puntos are referring to IQ scores.)

Comment: @LisaBeck - The way *raspado* is being used in the quote you found is completely different.  I will post a question on your behalf and then write an answer.  I just think this is the quickest way of clearing this up.  (I'm afraid if I ask you to post the question you might go whole hog on the background research -- but I think this can be a quickie -- however it is not my intention to steal a good question; so please feel free to post your own question, and ping me.  I would then transfer my answer and delete my question.)

Comment: Here's something funny: I looked up *raspado* in the DLE and it said "Refresco granizado."  I misread this the first three times I looked at it and thought it said "Refresco **organizado**"!

Comment: @aparente001  Yeah, I was thinking that it might deserve a post of its own.  Thank you for offering to write a Q&A on my behalf!  I look forward to reading it.  As for going whole hog on the background research, I actually don't know that I would have on this one.  My research is pretty much limited to what I can find on the web and my cursory search of this word really wasn't leading me to much, let alone any interesting rabbit holes for potential further discovery.  So I gladly, and with reverence, hand the baton to you on this one.  Your knowledge of Spanish is much greater than mine.

Answer (score 0):

*Raspado* has a lot of meanings, depending om which country you are and the context.

One can mean that you had shave your beard or heads hair. In Venezuela, Colombia, Mexico and Panama is ice in very small pieces with fruit syrup (same as the picture in these comments).

Another meaning is when the doctor takes a piece of skin from the uterus. And the last one as I know, is when a lab frays the surface of the bones.

Comment: When you say takes a bit of skin from the uterus do you mean the Pap test? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pap_test