# What is the meaning of 'raspado' when talking about IQ test scores?

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones

This question arose from a [comment by @LisaBeck](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21247/what-is-el-raspado#comment41760_21249) in relation to a question about "raspado" as a noun meaning *shaved ice*.

*El País* had an [article](https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/03/16/eps/1521200603_126765.html) that talks about super intelligence.  Here's the quote Lisa was curious about:

> ¿Acaso la distancia entre estos últimos y los que superan los 160 puntos no es mayor que la que existe entre los “raspados” y el resto que, en el 70% de los casos, se sitúa en la banda entre 87 y 114 puntos?

Question: what does *raspado* mean **in this context**? It doesn't seem to be a cold, sweet snack here.

Comment: El título y el cuerpo de la pregunta se contradicen. Hay muchos otros contextos aparte del gastronómico, y te estás centrando en uno concreto (el del artículo). Preguntar por otros significados en otros contextos (como hace el título) da pie a múltiples respuestas válidas. El cuerpo de la pregunta restringe a un contexto concreto, no a cualquiera que no sea el gastronómico. Deberías editar la pregutna par evitar confusión.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [aprobado raspado](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=aprobado%20raspado)
>
> (locución nominal masculina) ES, coloquial (nota mínima)
>
> barely passing grade. grade that barely scrapes by .

Aprobar raspado is "aprobar por los pelos". Back to the context of your question (my edits in bold)

> ¿Acaso la distancia entre estos últimos y los que superan los 160 puntos no es mayor que la que existe entre los [**que han pasado el criterio de corte<sup>*</sup>**] “raspados” y el resto que, en el 70% de los casos, se sitúa en la banda entre 87 y 114 puntos?

That "criterio de corte" is whatever you consider to "pass" or to be included in a certain category. This could be translated as

> Isn't the distance between the latter and those above 160 points greater than that between those who **barely made it** and the rest, which in 70% of the cases is in the band between 87 and 114 points?

Comment: I just remembered an idiom in English that's similar: If he passed the test, but barely: *He scraped by*.

Answer (score 2):

"Raspado" también puede ser una [prueba ginecológica](https://www.enfemenino.com/embarazo/raspado-de-la-matriz-s454979.html). Es una palabra que si la dices suelta como en "tengo un raspado", suena un poco rara sobre todo entre mujeres, mejor no la uses si no estás seguro.

No es el significado que tiene en el texto que has puesto pero el título pregunta por otros significados en general.

Comment: ¡Interesante respuesta! Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Tu imagen de perfil me recuerda una que tenía walen...

Comment: @walen No eres el único fan de la Dragonlance / Reinos Olvidados / Ravenloft del sitio no. Aunque esos años quedan lejos ya, muy lejos...

Comment: No voy a dar voto negativo ni levantar un flag, pero hay un problema con esta respuesta (en realidad, un problema de redacción en la pregunta). Aunque el título pregunta por otros significados aparte del contexto gastronómico (lo que podría ser una pregunta "too broad" con múltiples soluciones) el cuerpo de la pregunta sí especifica un contexto concreto (el del artículo que cita). Hay una contradicción entre el título y el cuerpo de la pregunta.  Esta respuesta es válida según el título de la pregunta, pero no según el cuerpo.

Comment: Sorry!  I'd change the title to be more consistent but that wouldn't be fair to @Astinus.  Oh well....